# Chemical Process Control - degrees of freedom in a stirred tank heater

Tags: chemical-engineering, modeling

I'm taking a course on Process Control, and I've been using Stephanopoulos's Chemical Process Control to study. I have a doubt about the degrees of freedom (DOF) analysis performed in one of the examples solved in the book, as follows: Consider a stirred tank heater, where a liquid enters the tank with a volumetric flow rate of $F_{i}$ ($ft^3/min$), and temperature $T_{i}$ ($ºF$). The liquid is heated with steam in the tank. Let $F$ and $T$ be the flow rate and temperature of the effluent stream. There is a single physical inlet stream and a single physical outlet stream. Perfect mixing is assumed in the tank, and the density of the liquid is constant.

In order to determine how the temperature in the tank ($T$) and the liquid level ($h$) change with time, a mathematical model consisting of the following equations is needed:

$A \dfrac{dh}{dt} = F_{i} - F$

$Ah\dfrac{dT}{dt} = F(T_{i} - T) + \dfrac{Q}{\rho c_{p}}$

Regarding the available DOF:
no. variables = 6 ($h$, $T$, $F_i$, $F$, $T_i$, and $Q$)
no. equations = 2 (see above)
Hence, DOF = 4.

Then, Stephanopoulos states that this DOF analysis holds if and only if $F$ is determined by a pump (i.e., constant-speed one) or a compressor or a **valve**, but *shouldn’t a valve introduce an additional equation*? If we suppose that a valve is indeed installed in the line, then we should consider in the DOF analysis the flow-through valve equation, that is, $F = C_v f(x) \sqrt{ \left( \dfrac{\Delta P_v}{\rho} \right)}$? So, the former DOF = 4 should actually be equal to 3. Or am I missing something?
On the other hand, if there were no valve or whatsoever, then the liquid would be allowed to flow freely (under the hydrostatic pressure of the liquid) through an orifice, thus calling anyway for an additional equation ($F= \beta \sqrt{h}$), which would have reduced the DOF by one.

Comment: Valve probably retains a form of adjustability so it converts a DoF instead of removing it...